# How to catch a "connection reset by peer" error in C socket?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, recv

I have a C++ and Qt application which part of it implements a C socket client. Some time ago by app crashed because something happened with the server; the only thing I got from that crash was a message in Qt Creator's Application Output stating

> recv_from_client: Connection reset by peer

I did some research on the web about this "connection reset by peer" error and while some threads here in SO and other places did managed to explain what is going on, none of them tells how to handle it - that is, how can I "catch" the error and continue my application without a crash (particularly the method where I read from the server is inside a while loop, so I'ld like to stop the while loop and enter in another place of my code that will try to re-establish the connection).

So how can I catch this error to handle it appropriately? Don't forget that my code is actually C++ with Qt - the C part is a library which calls the socket methods.

**EDIT**

Btw, the probable method from which the crash originated (given the "recv_from_client" part of the error message above) was:

```
int hal_socket_read_from_client(socket_t *obj, u_int8_t *buffer, int size)
{
    struct s_socket_private * const socket_obj = (struct s_socket_private *)obj;
    int retval = recv(socket_obj->client_fd, buffer, size, MSG_DONTWAIT); //last = 0

    if (retval < 0)
        perror("recv_from_client");

    return retval;
}
```

Note: I'm not sure if by the time this error occurred, the `recv` configuration was with *MSG_DONTWAIT* or with *0*.

Comment: What does your code currently do if the socket method returns an error?

Comment: When you say "crash", do you mean that an exception is being thrown?  If so, then simply use a `try/catch` block around the method that is failing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If one of the socket methods returns an error, a message is written in the application console (with QDebug) and (at least in this case) the software should continue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau by "crash" I mean abrupt, undesired process termination. I can't catch it with `try-catch` becase its the error is generated from within the C code; no such system there!

Comment: The fault lies in the code that calls `hal_socket_read_from_client`. The output shows that the `perror` code executed and so the function returned something less than zero. The calling code then, apparently, blew up. So the problem lies in whatever calls this function.

Comment: Also, your `hal_socket_read_from_client` function is basically unusable. If you're going to pass `MSG_DONTWAIT` to it, but you only return a -1 on error, how can the caller tell if the error was fatal or non-fatal?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz to be honest, I think there is a confusion in the bug report... The `hal...` method I presented is never used in the client, only in the server application (and when a error occur, it just set a break to a while-loop). It could be the case that and error occurred in the client which invalidated the socket_descriptor, thus leading to the error, but what actually crashed was a later call to a `hal_send_to_client` method with a SIGPIPE thanks to the broken descriptor. Unfortunately the bug report doesn't help =/

Comment: @Momergil Invalidating a socket descriptor doesn't cause ECONNRESET or broken pipes or application crashes. Receiving an RST from the peer causes ECONNRESET, and coding bugs cause crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Just examine `errno` when `read()` returns a negative result.

There is normally no crash involved.

```
while (...) {
    ssize_t amt = read(sock, buf, size);
    if (amt > 0) {
        // success
    } else if (amt == 0) {
        // remote shutdown (EOF)
    } else {
        // error

        // Interrupted by signal, try again
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;

        // This is fatal... you have to close the socket and reconnect
        // handle errno == ECONNRESET here

        // If you use non-blocking sockets, you also have to handle
        // EWOULDBLOCK / EAGAIN here

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only `EINTR`, `EAGAIN`, and `EWOULDBLOCK` are non-fatal and `recv()` can be retried. Anything else should be treated as a fatal error, so assume the connection is lost. Don't single out `ECONNRESET` as other errors can occur.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an exception or a signal. You can't catch it. Instead, you get an error which tells you that the connection has been resetted when trying to work on that socket.

```
int rc = recv(fd, ..., ..., ..., ...);

if (rc == -1)
{ 
  if (errno == ECONNRESET)
    /* handle it; there isn't much to do, though.*/
  else
     perror("Error while reading");
}
```

As I've written, there isn't much you can do. If you're using some I/O multiplexer, you may want to remove that file descriptor from further monitoring.